# Describe the memory consumption of this metaprogram

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I found this working code in a book on Metaprogramming -

```
template<unsigned long N>
struct binary
{
    static unsigned const value = binary<N/10>::value *2 + N%10;    
};

template<>
struct binary<0>
{
    static unsigned const value = 0;
};

int main()
{
    unsigned x = binary<101010>::value;
    cout << x;
}
```

My question is - where is the memory for `value` allocated? Is it allocated on the data segment?

Also, the book says that this code results in a cascade of template instantiations which computes the result in a manner similar to recursion. Does that mean for each template instantiation, a new `unsigned` is allocated on the data segment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`value` has no definition. Such static data members can only be used in ways that don't require them to have an address (they cannot be *odr-used*). Their values will be inlined, as though you had `unsigned x = 42;`.

Of course the *compiler* has to somehow instantiate all the template specializations and calculate `binary<101010>::value`. But that doesn't matter anymore after compilation is complete.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a good C++ compiler, no memory gets allocated anywhere. The C++ compiler will completely optimize away this class, and use the calculated constant directly, in whatever code uses it.